# Java threads slow down towards the end of processing

Tags: java, multithreading, lucene, java.util.concurrent

I have a Java program that takes in a text file containing a list of text files and processes each line separately. To speed up the processing, I make use of threads using an ExecutorService with a FixedThreadPool with 24 threads. The machine has 24 cores and 48GB of RAM.

The text file that I'm processing has 2.5 million lines. I find that for the first 2.3 million lines or so things run very well with high CPU utilization. However, beyond some point (at around the 2.3 lines), the performance degenerates with only a single CPU being utilized and my program pretty much grinding to a halt.

I've investigated a number of causes, made sure all my file handles are closed, and increased the amount of memory supplied to the JVM. However, regardless of what I change, performance always degrades towards the end. I've even tried on text files containing fewer lines and once again performance decreases towards the end of processing the file.

In addition to the standard Java concurrency libraries, the code also makes use of Lucene libraries for text processing and analysis.

When I don't thread this code, the performance is constant and doesn't degenerate towards the end. I know this is a shot in the dark and it's hard to describe what is going on, but I thought I would just see if anyone has any ideas as to what might be causing this degeneration in performance towards the end.

**Edit**

After the comments I've received, I've pasted a stack trace [here](http://paste.kde.org/727556/). As you can see, it doesn't appear as if any of the threads are blocking. Also, when profiling, the GC was not at 100% when things slowed down. In fact, both CPU and GC utilization were at 0% most of the time, with the CPU spiking occasionally to process a few files and then stopping again.

**Code for executing threads**

```
 BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);
 String line;
 while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) { //index each line
     Runnable worker = new CharikarHashThreader(line, bits, minTokens);
     executor.execute(worker);
 }
 read.close();
```

Comment: Have you checked for leaks or such in a profiler? Have you made sure there is nothing that could deadlock your threads? Can you show us some code?

Comment: So with 200k lines still queued up, it slows?  Have you watched memory to make sure it's not in GC hell.  Do you queue one line at a time or a collection of lines?

Comment: You should definitively be using a size limited `BlockingQueue` instead of queueing all of the lines at once.

Comment: As @Gray says, GC seems a reasonnable guess when a JVM stalls at 100% of one CPU...

Short of profiling, have you tried plugging out Lucene to see if the slowdown is somehow related to that part of your code ?

Have you made sure you are not piling operations up in some sort of Collection with put/remove/get operations that are not in constant time ? (e.g. searching a particular element of a LinkedList, popping random elements of an ArrayList, ...)

Comment: Any chance the threads are actually still running but are hung somehow?  Have you dumped the stack-traces to see if you see the threads all jammed in some code or on some lock.  Maybe spider code?  Any chance the throughput drops not just at the end but over time?

Comment: is it always around the 2.3 millions lines mark, or does it also happen if you reduce the line number to say 2 millions?

Comment: I've tried with a million lines as well and it also slows at some point. Based on all the comments, it definitely seems like this is a GC problem. I'll look into some of the suggestions made here and report back after more experimentation. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post your code over creation ExecutorService and processing the file ? I think it is the problem with ExecutorService Thread handling and the queue..

Comment: I've added the code to the original post

Comment: @KyleW Have you found anything ?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I haven't found a working solution yet. I've experimented with some of the suggestions made here without any luck. I'm starting to suspect that the problem may be in the text files that I'm processing, so I'm going to experiment with another set of 2.5 million files and see if it works then.

Comment: Okay, I ran this on another set of 2.5 million files and it finished successfully. I guess this means that some file(s) is/are causing problems. What I'll do is set a runtime limit on the threads and hopefully that should sort things out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds alot like a Garbage Collection / Memory Issue.

When the Garbage Collection runs it pauses all threads so that the GC thread can do its "is this collectable garbage" analysis without things changing on it.  While the GC is running you'll see exactly 1 thread at 100%, the other threads will be stuck at 0%.

I would consider adding a few Runtime.freeMemory() calls  (or using a profiler) to see if the "grind to a halt" occurs during GC.

I'd also trying running your program on just the first 10k lines of your file to see if that works.

I'd also look to see if your program is building too many intermediate Strings when it should be using StringBuilders.

It sounds to me like you need to profile your memory usage.

Comment: Having 1 thread at 100% while the other are stuck is exactly what is happening. I'll look into some of these suggestions and report back. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure anymore if this is a GC problem. I'm profiling using VisualVM and when things grid to a halt, both CPU usage and GC usage are at 0% or close to it. However, all my threads are now in a "wait" state, so it seems this may have more to do with the threads than memory.

Comment: This also corresponds with a major increase in memory usage towards the time that things grind to a halt.

Comment: Also, not sure if it's relevant, but most of the memory is currently being used by java.util.LinkedList$Node

Comment: Sounds like using an ArrayList instead of a LinkedList could save the memory overhead associated with storing a very large list in a LinkedList

Comment: I finally tracked it down to a 2.1GB file among the 2.5 million text files I was processing. This was definitely the problem. Thanks for all the suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought it was GC problems as well but I'm not so sure give the following information.

> I've even tried on text files containing fewer lines and once again performance decreases towards the end of processing the file.

My guess is that the threads haven't quit but are jammed somehow.  I would recommend taking a thread dump (`kill -QUIT pid` under *nix or by using `jstack`) and see where the threads are.  This will help you identify if they are jammed somewhere.

I suspect that your program starts off with 24 threads running but over time you lose one and then another.  Although it seems like there is a dramatic performance drop off at the end I wonder if the program has been getting slower and slower from the start.

- Watch for sockets without proper connection or IO timeouts.
- Maybe some sort of lock contention that is blocking threads?
- Maybe something that Lucene is doing is either causing contention or is blocking your threads.  As mentioned by @GPI, I would try commenting out the Lucene calls and see if the problem goes away.  Again, a stack-trace will also show this to you.

Once you determine where the threads are blocking on, you will need to either resolve the lock issues, add timeouts to network calls, or otherwise fix the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gray. I've edited my original post with a link to a stack trace. As you can see, it doesn't appear as if any of the threads are blocking. GC utilization is also at 0% most of the time.