# I have tried to optimize (memory) my program, but GC is still making it lag

Tags: java, garbage-collection, profiling

I have written a piece of software in Java that checks if proxies are working by sending a HTTP request using the proxy.

It takes around 30,000 proxies from a database, then attempts to check if they are operational. The proxies received from the database used to be returned as an `ArrayList<String>`, but have been changed to `Deque<String>` for reasons stated below.

The way the program works is there is a `ProxyRequest` object that stores the IP & Port as a String and int respectively. The `ProxyRequest` object has a method `isWorkingProxy()` which attempts to send a request using a proxy and returns a `boolean` on whether it was successful.

This `ProxyRequest` object is wrapped around by a `RunnableProxyRequest` object that calls `super.isWorkingProxy()` in the overrided `run()` method. Based on the response from `super.isWorkingProxy()`, the `RunnableProxyRequest` object updates a MySQL database.

Do note that the updating of the MySQL database is `synchronized()`.

> It runs on 750 threads using a FixedThreadPool (on a VPS), but towards
>   the end, it becomes very slow (stuck on ~50 threads), which obviously
>   implies the garbage collector is working. This is the problem.

I have attempted the following to improve the lag, it does not seem to work:

1) Using a `Deque<String>` proxies and using `Deque.pop()` to obtain the `String` in which the proxy is. This (I believe), continuously makes the `Deque<String>` smaller, which should improve lag caused by the GC.

2) Set the `con.setConnectTimeout(this.timeout);`, where `this.timeout = 5000;` This way, the connection should return a result in 5 seconds. If not, the thread is completed and should no longer be active in the threadpool.

Besides this, I don't know any other way I can improve performance.

Can anyone recommend a way for me to improve performance to avoid / stop lagging towards the end of the threads by the GC? I know there is a Stackoverflow question about this ([Java threads slow down towards the end of processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064544/java-threads-slow-down-towards-the-end-of-processing)), but I have tried everything in the answer and it has not worked for me.

Thank you for your time.

Code snippets:

Loop adding threads to the `FixedThreadPool`:

```
//This code is executed recursively (at the end, main(args) is called again)
//Create the threadpool for requests
//Threads is an argument that is set to 750.
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
Deque<String> proxies = DB.getProxiesToCheck();

while(proxies.isEmpty() == false) {
    try {
        String[] split = proxies.pop().split(":");

        Runnable[] checks = new Runnable[] {
            //HTTP check
            new RunnableProxyRequest(split[0], split[1], Proxy.Type.HTTP, false),
            //SSL check
            new RunnableProxyRequest(split[0], split[1], Proxy.Type.HTTP, true),
            //SOCKS check
            new RunnableProxyRequest(split[0], split[1], Proxy.Type.SOCKS, false)
            //Add more checks to this list as time goes...
        };

        for(Runnable check : checks) {
            executor.submit(check);
        }

    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

`ProxyRequest` class:

```
//Proxy details
private String proxyIp;
private int proxyPort;
private Proxy.Type testingType;

//Request details
private boolean useSsl;

public ProxyRequest(String proxyIp, String proxyPort, Proxy.Type testingType, boolean useSsl) {
    this.proxyIp = proxyIp;
    try {
        this.proxyPort = Integer.parseInt(proxyPort);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        this.proxyPort = -1;
    }
    this.testingType = testingType;
    this.useSsl = useSsl;
}

public boolean isWorkingProxy() {
    //Case of an invalid proxy
    if(proxyPort == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    HttpURLConnection con = null;

    //Perform checks on URL
    //IF any exception occurs here, the proxy is obviously bad.
    try {
        URL url = new URL(this.getTestingUrl());
        //Create proxy
        Proxy p = new Proxy(this.testingType, new InetSocketAddress(this.proxyIp, this.proxyPort));
        //No redirect
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        //Open connection with proxy
        con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(p);
        //Set the request method
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //Set max timeout for a request.
        con.setConnectTimeout(this.timeout);
    } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("The testing URL is bad. Please fix this.");
        return false;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    try(
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            ) {

        String inputLine = null; StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }

        //A valid proxy!
        return con.getResponseCode() > 0;

    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`RunnableProxyRequest` class:

```
public class RunnableProxyRequest extends ProxyRequest implements Runnable {


    public RunnableProxyRequest(String proxyIp, String proxyPort, Proxy.Type testingType, boolean useSsl) {

        super(proxyIp, proxyPort, testingType, useSsl);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String test = super.getTest();

        if(super.isWorkingProxy()) {

            System.out.println("-- Working proxy: " + super.getProxy() + " | Test: " +  test);

            this.updateDB(true, test);

        } else {
            System.out.println("-- Not working: " + super.getProxy() + " | Test: " +  test);

            this.updateDB(false, test);
        }   


    }

    private void updateDB(boolean success, String testingType) {
        switch(testingType) {
            case "SSL":
                DB.updateSsl(super.getProxyIp(), super.getProxyPort(), success);
                break;
            case "HTTP":
                DB.updateHttp(super.getProxyIp(), super.getProxyPort(), success);
                break;
            case "SOCKS":
                DB.updateSocks(super.getProxyIp(), super.getProxyPort(), success);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`DB` class:

```
//Locker for async 
private static Object locker = new Object();

private static void executeUpdateQuery(String query, String proxy, int port, boolean toSet) {
    synchronized(locker) {
        //Some prepared statements here.
    }
}
```

Comment: If most of your threads are fast but some are slow, most likely they are tried up trying to get an answer from the server they are contacting.  Your GC pauses will be worst when you are doing the most work not the tail end.

Comment: Yes, but like I mentioned I set the timeout to 5 seconds. So even if they are trying to get an answer, they would have stopped trying after 5 seconds whether or not they got an answer.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Absolutely. Just posted some code.

Comment: Could it be an approach to reduce the size of your List of proxies? With 30000 proxies and 750 threads you would have to start each thread about 40 times. Instead you could let your thread make the database requests, reading one proxy at a time, testing the proxy and then updating the proxy state when it is finished (or not). The memory consuming work load (holding and iterating through the list) would then be handled by the database as well as synchronization and your GC could concentrate on the threads.

Comment: Hmmm could be. Thanks for the idea. Let me make some changes and tell you how it all works out :)

Comment: Ok the method is way too slow. Since I use a SELECT * and ORDER BY, executing the statement several times is way too slow (and I believe MySQL queues statements, so it isn't asynchronous either!) As for the result, it never got to the end of it... I think part of your answer is correct though. I'll try to re-use the same 750 threads instead of closing and restarting them so many times.

Comment: Alright so I tried running 300 threads with 300 proxies in total. Even the first 300 threads lagged quite a bit. Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @ILoveKali I have found network libraries are not aggressive enough in shutting down a connection when things go really wrong. Timeouts tend to work best when the connection is fine. YMMV

Comment: I see. I'm not using an external lib by the way. Just Java's default HttpURLConnection

Comment: @PeterLawrey you legend! You fixed it. Check my answer :)

Comment: Just some notes on the coding style. Don’t use `proxies.isEmpty() == false`, use `!proxies.isEmpty()` (not … is empty). When you initialize an array in the form `ElementType[] variable = new ElementType[] { elements };`, you don’t need to write `new ElementType[]`, you can just use `ElementType[] variable = { elements };`. And don’t catch an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` that way. Use an explicit test, i.e. `if(split.length < 2) continue;`. That way, you will always know under which condition you want to `continue`, even when looking at the code years later.

Comment: I prefer using `== false`. Makes it more readable imo (at least for me). I don't think it makes a difference how I would initialize `Element[]`. I agree with the `if(split.length < 2)`, will add the change soon. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) for guiding me to the solution! :)

His comment:

> @ILoveKali I have found network libraries are not aggressive enough in
>   shutting down a connection when things go really wrong. Timeouts tend
>   to work best when the connection is fine. YMMV

So I did some research, and found that I had to also use the method `setReadTimeout(this.timeout);`. Previously, I was only using `setConnectTimeout(this.timeout);`!

Thanks to this post ([HttpURLConnection timeout defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199702/httpurlconnection-timeout-defaults)) that explained the following:

> Unfortunately, in my experience, it appears using these defaults can
>   lead to an unstable state, depending on what happens with your
>   connection to the server. If you use an HttpURLConnection and don't
>   explicitly set (at least read) timeouts, your connection can get into
>   a permanent stale state. By default. So always set setReadTimeout to
>   "something" or you might orphan connections (and possibly threads
>   depending on how your app runs).

So the final answer is: The GC was doing just fine, it was not responsible for the lag. The threads were simply stuck FOREVER at a single number because I did not set the read timeout, and so the `isWorkingProxy()` method never got a result and kept reading.